# How to get the same application instance handle from QT and WinApi

Tags: qt, winapi

My QT application uses WinApi library.
Now I have the following code:

```
//main.cpp
qDebug() << "main::instance = " << qApp; //0x29fe18
//lib.cpp
qDebug() << "library::instance = " << GetModuleHandle(NULL); // 0x400000
```

As you see, I'm getting different handles while my app has only one thread flow.

What's wrong?

***Edit:*** 
Yes, I guessed that those are kind of different things.
Question is: how do I get thread handle from both places (if code running from the same thread - I should get the same handle value, if there's 2 threads - I should get 2 different thread handles)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know what `qApp` is. Presumably it's a pointer to the global instance of `QApplication`. That's a C++ object instance in your process.

On the other hand `GetModuleHandle(NULL)` is the base address of your executable module.

These two things are completely different. You should not expect them to be the same.

According to your edit you aren't interested in either of these things and actually want to identify threads. For Win32 code you use `GetCurrentThreadId`. For Qt use `QThread::currentThreadId()`.

Comment: edited question in order to clarify my problem, please, take a look :)

Comment: I've answered that second question now